# Grunt Uglify weird characters at last line leading to no changes

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am working since month with Grunt Watch, which is using Uglify to minify Javascript files and also generating a .map file which worked perfectly since yesterday.

When I now do `grunt watch` and save a Javascript file, Grunt workes like intended and runs the tasks which copy the Javascript file into the public area and generating the `filename.js` and `filename.js.map` file into the public area.

Now I am refreshing the page to look my changes, but instead of my changes, the browser seems loading the old Javascript file (Yes, I am using version like `filename.js?v=....`).

When I look in the source code and open the Javascript file, at the end of the file following weird characters are there:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=filename.js.map��������������������
```

I am using Chrome as my browser and PHPStorm as my IDE.

I tried to convert to UTF-8, UTF-8 without BOM, changed line Feeds to LF and CRLF, but nothing seems to be the solution.

I also displayed *all invisible characters* to look if there is something hidden, but there is nothing.

Inside the generated file there is the `console.log('Test');` I written into, but in the same file I opened in the source code, the `console.log('Test');` is not there:

Open file in any IDE: [public/js/filename.js]

```
... function(){l=!0,console.log("Test"),c.setTimeout(fun ...
```

Open file in any Browser: [/js/filename.js]

```
... function(){l=!0,c.setTimeout(fun ...
```

If I delete the 2 files in the public folder, change something in the original file and save, grunt is uglifying and copying everything and it's working! But just this one time.. the next changes leading to the same weird characters and no changes to the file in the browser again.

Like I said: The whole process I am doing worked for months! But since yesterday it's not working anymore.

I didn't installed/patched anything. This behaviour came from one to another second.

Operating System is:

```
Linux packer-virtualbox-iso-14225xxxxx 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1 x86_
```

I am searching since yesterday, but can't find any solution or idea what is wrong.

Comment: Are you using nginx?

Comment: Yes. I am using nginx

Comment: We had the same problem, here you go :D -> https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640

Comment: added it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Used to have the same problem. You should turn off your sendfile in nginx.

```
sendfile off;
```

see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640

Comment: Thanks @Christophe, I will test this right after it happens again and mark your answer as correct, if it's working. This could take a while :)

Answer (score 0):

I just restartet my computer and it seems working right now.

But if anyone has a suggestion to prevent this or solving this problem in the future, I would be happy to hear from it! If in the next few days no answer comes, I will mark my answer as solution.